# R function that calculate correlation between two elements of a data frame if condition is meet

Tags: function, r

So I've been trying to make this function work for days..

function behaviour should be as follows:

1. go throw a number of specified csv's = id
2. read.csv's and rbind them all in one dataframe
3. remove all rows that have na values and keep only complete ones. condition 1
4. Then if sum of data[row_number,col_1] + data[row_number,col_2] > threshold,
   then we keep the row, else row is deleted.
5. finally correlate element-1 with element-2 and return a list of all correlations done.

my code:

```
corr <- function(directory,threshold = 0,id = 1:332)   {

  file.list <- list.files(directory, full.names = T)
  dat <- data.frame()
  for(i in id) {
  dat <- rbind(dat,read.csv(file.list[i]))
  }
  complete_rows <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
  z <- data.frame()
  z <- complete_rows[,2:3]
  y <- data.frame()
  y <- rowSums(z) > threshold
  x <- data.frame()
  x <- z[y,1:2]
  for( i in x[1:nrow(x),]){
   cor(x[i,1],x[i,2], method = c("pearson"))
   }
      }
```

my problem is in step 5 correlating both elements and returning correlations..

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your code could use some clean-up. For example, you don't need `z <- data.frame()` and I also think that `y <- data.frame()` and `x <- data.frame()` is useless. To your problem: Could you try `for (i in 1:nrow(x))` instead of `for( i in x[1:nrow(x),])` This could solve your problem. However, I cannot replicate your question/problem with the code you provided.

Comment: I changed it a little bit at the end to                                                   x <- data.frame()
  x1 <- z[y,1]
  x2 <- z[y,2]
  mapply( cor, x1 , x2 )                                                                                  now it prints out all na's

Comment: Try it without a for loop at the end. `cor(x[,1], x[,2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   corr  <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
     files <- list.files(directory, full.names = T)
     dat2 <- lapply(files, function(x) na.omit(read.csv(x)))
     size <- unlist(lapply(dat2, nrow))
     cors <- lapply(dat2[size > threshold], function(x) cor(x['nitrate'], x['sulfate']))
     res <- unname(unlist(cors)) 
   }
```